# Displaying the name instead of ID - YII2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In my form I have the category_id, In the drop-down, it displays the name but after saving it displays the ID, how do I display the name instead of the ID?

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'category_id')->dropDownlist(
     ArrayHelper::map(Category::find()->all(), 'id', 'category_name'),
     [
         'prompt' => 'Select Category',
         'onchange' => '$.post( "index.php?r=sub-cat/lists&id='.'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
                $( "select#tickets-sub_category" ).html( data );
          });'
     ]); 
?>
```

What I have tried so far in the view is this:

```
[
   'label' => $model->category_id->getAttributeLabel('category_name'),
   'value' => $model->category_id->category_name
]
```

But I'm getting an error: Call to a member function getAttributeLabel() on integer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please try this code in your grid-view.

```
['label'=>'Category Name',
'value' => function ($data) {
     return Category::findOne(['id'=>$data->category_id])->category_name;
},]
```

Comment: Is this on the category model or the view.php?

Comment: please use it in grid-view

Comment: How about in the view.php? Am I going to do similar one like that? Edit: I've tried using it but it says array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

Comment: are you using grid-view?
in your view.php ?

Comment: No, detail view.

Answer (score 1):

Or try this code if you want to display category name instead of id anywhere on the view
Assuming that you have two tables
1. Catgeory (id, name)
2. Post (id, category, title)
In your Post model

```
public function getCategoryId()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\path\to\models\Category::className(), ['id' 
        => 'category']);
    }
/**
 * @getCategoryName
 *
 */
public function getCategoryName()
{
    return $this->categoryId ? $this->categoryId->name : '- no category -';
}
```

Now you can use categoryName ?> anywhere on your view

In case if you are using GridView
Just change attribute to categoryName